# How to create new table from an existing table in google bigquery based on triggers?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to GCP. I have hooked my bigquery with my ERP. This gives me a transaction table in bigquery. The transaction query has tran_id as primary key and looks like the below:

| tran_id | date | amount | quantity | item_id | cust_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 UTC | 2000 | 2 | 000000124 | 01 |
| 2 | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 UTC | 3500 | 1 | 000000122 | 02 |
| 3 | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 UTC | 4000 | 3 | 000000124 | 03 |

Based on the transaction table, I want to create a new table inside bigquery, let's call it customer, and this table will fetch data from the transaction table and will have customer_id as primary key and should look like below:

| cust_id | Length | Recency | Frequency | Monetary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 9000 |
| 02 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 18000 |
| 03 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 20000 |

I have written a query for this customer table which successfully returns me the above expected table. The query looks like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  customer_id AS Phone,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), MIN(trans_date), DAY) AS Length,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), MAX(trans_date), DAY) AS Recency,
  COUNT(transaction_id) AS Frequency,
  SUM(net_amount) AS Monetary
FROM
  `nice-cyclist-380910.dynamics_f_o_production_test_2_jz_dx_g18_kz_9l7_oz_mz_i_ak1yv_jc.order_completed`
GROUP BY
  user_id
ORDER BY
  Frequency DESC
```

Now, the challenge is how do I create and auto-maintain this new customer table. The flow I want to implement is: whenever a new row is created in the transaction table, it should check the customer table.

1. If that cust_id already exists in the customer table, then it should
   update the records like Length, Recency, Frequency and Monetary.
2. If the cust_id doesn't exist in the customer table, it should create a
   new row in the customer table and calculate Length, Recency, Frequency and Monetary.

How this triggering is possible? What GCP products/tools could help me achieve this? How will the architecture and integration look like?

Comment: Are you looking for [view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_view_statement)?

Comment: No. I want a proper table to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

there are few options

**Option 1:**

this based option is minimal configuration

1. create materialized view of the base transaction table - see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create#create) here
2. Wrap your query with additional condition to your query to check changes to materialized view create in step 1 above to as a [scheduled query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries) that will run certain frequency as per your need.
   This should give you the outcome, however not on trigger based.

3: refresh the materialized [view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-manage#manual_refresh)

**Option 2:**

This is using trigger using eventrc, see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/targets#triggers) here
This option however has a bit more configuration and using several other google services, like eventrc as source trigger and then target to be either cloud function or cloud workflow.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will option 1 be more expensive? Since it will run the scheduled query on the whole transaction table every time and then give a view?

Comment: it depends, as per documentation, the scheduled query is same as manual queries. If you reduce the frequency in schedule and find a optimal window of refresh could be way forward. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#pricing

Comment: HI there, Also check this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-history looks like your use case can be also achieved using table value function using change history :-)

Comment: if this is answered, pls mark this as answered :-)